# what i need to do here make css animation keyframes (wiggle) work here?

Tags: css, animation

can you please check why animation is not working ,do need to do something something else?
this is firstime am using keyframes animation ,do this need any prereq to setup css animation?

in last list item i need to add my css animation (wiggle) but not working

```css
@keyframes wiggle {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateZ(10deg);
  }
}

.main-nav__item--cta {
  animation: wiggle 200ms 3s 8 forwards;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav__items">
  <li class="main-nav__item">
    <a href="Packages/index.html">Packages</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav__item">
    <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--cta">
    <a href="start-hosting/index.html">Start Hosting</a>
  </li>`


</ul>
```

Comment: First of all, `translateZ(10deg)` is not a thing. Translation is the moving of an element along one (or more) axis, and that requires a _length_, not an _angle_.

Comment: @OliverHeward `3s` is `animation-delay`

Comment: @OliverHeward one is for duration and another one is delay

Comment: animation-duration: 200ms;
    animation-timing-function: ease;
    animation-delay: 3s;
    animation-iteration-count: 8;
    animation-direction: alternate;
    animation-fill-mode: none;
    animation-play-state: running;
    animation-name: wiggle;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `translateZ()` must be used with a length unit, not an angle unit
Then you need a `perspective` value on the parent element of the transformed element.
The transformed element cannot be `display: inline;`
Then use `animation-direction: alternate` so that you have a smnooth back-and-forth animation.

```css
@keyframes wiggle {
  from {
    transform: translateZ(0);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateZ(100px);
  }
}

.main-nav__item--cta a span {
  animation: wiggle 200ms 3s 16 both alternate ease-in-out;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: underline;
}

.main-nav__item--cta a {
  perspective: 1000px;
  display: inline-block;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<ul class="main-nav__items">
  <li class="main-nav__item">
    <a href="Packages/index.html">Packages</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav__item">
    <a href="customers/index.html">Customers</a>
  </li>

  <li class="main-nav__item main-nav__item--cta">
    <a href="start-hosting/index.html"><span>Start Hosting</span></a>
  </li>`


</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
  animation: wiggle 3s 8;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```